# How to Open HTML file using Java?

Tags: java

I try to open HTML file from local (In my system) by Java program. I tried some of the program got through stack overflow but its not working as much.

**For E.G.:** I have this small HTML file.

```html
<html>
  <head> 
    Test Application
  </head>
  <body>
     This is test application
  </body>
</html>
```

**My Java code:**

```
Runtime rTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String url = "D:/hi.html";
String browser = "C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe ";
Process pc = rTime.exec(browser + url);
pc.waitFor();
```

Any solution or tips appreciated.

Comment: *"How to Opening HTML file in chrome..?"*  Why 'Chrome' as opposed to the user's default browser?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I would prefer to use default browser

```
File htmlFile = new File(url);
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());
```

Comment: I didn't negated your question, and dont know why someone did, your question is 100% valid, so I voted it up xD

Comment: If the user has assigned a custom "open with" action to the file extension like "html" then this will NOT open the browser, but the program the user has linked it with.... This is not a solution at all!

Comment: URI uri = new URL(url).toURI();   Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);  using File did not work for me, using url seems to work

Comment: @thesaint How is this not a solution? Such a requirement was never specified.

Comment: what is the way to open it in mac

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code for a method that fails gracefully.

Note that the string can be the location of an `html` file.

```
/**
* If possible this method opens the default browser to the specified web page.
* If not it notifies the user of webpage's url so that they may access it
* manually.
* 
* @param url
*            - this can be in the form of a web address (http://www.mywebsite.com)
*            or a path to an html file or SVG image file e.t.c 
*/
public static void openInBrowser(String url)
{
    try
        {
            URI uri = new URL(url).toURI();
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
            if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE))
                desktop.browse(uri);
        }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
            /*
             *  I know this is bad practice 
             *  but we don't want to do anything clever for a specific error
             */
            e.printStackTrace();

            // Copy URL to the clipboard so the user can paste it into their browser
            StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(url);
            Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            clpbrd.setContents(stringSelection, null);
            // Notify the user of the failure
            WindowTools.informationWindow("This program just tried to open a webpage." + "\n"
                + "The URL has been copied to your clipboard, simply paste into your browser to access.",
                    "Webpage: " + url);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
URI oURL = new URI(url);
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(oURL);
```

Apart from that, make sure that file is already opened in your desired browser.
Check the icon on the file, If it is showing like a text file, you might have already opened with Text file. **So change the default program to the desired program.**