# How can I run the html file in browser using java program?

Tags: java

This is my code. I am able to open browser but it will not load the html source.

```
class Browser {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        try {
            Runtime rtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

            String url = "‪C:/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/DD.html";
            String brow = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Internet   Explorer/iexplore.exe";

            Process pc = rtime.exec(brow + url);    
            pc.waitFor();       
         } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("\n\n" + e.getMessage());
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517434/how-to-open-html-file-using-java

Comment: is your DD.html really in the the Internet Explorer program directory? You shouldn't really be changing anything in there

Comment: Yes it is in the internet explorer program directory and  i got my answer ,thanks for showing your interest

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too many spaces in the `brow` value - I presume that's just a formatting issue in the question.

Using the single-argument version of `exec` splits the input string by spaces, so your code will try to execute a command `C:/Program` and pass it arguments `"Files"`, `"(x86)/Internet"`, `"Explorer/iexplore.exeC:/Program"`, `"Files"`, etc.

Note that `"Explorer/iexplore.exeC:/Program"` - because you concatenated the two strings without a space.

You *could* resolve these issues by passing an array of strings to `exec()` instead of using the single-string version, but you're better off using [`Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI))